# R and Java - rJava error on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, r, rjava, rjdbc

I am trying to make a `con` using `rjdbc` and `rJava` packages and i am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\user\dir>Rscript rjdbc.r
Loading required package: methods
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava'
```

Additionally i get this pop-up error window

`This program can't start because jvm.dll is missing from your computer`

I am using java

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

R version is

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

and my `env variables` on `Windows 8.1 Pro - 64-bit OS` are currently

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8
path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin\server
```

I have read tons of similar questions but still no success. Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I had issues with `rJava` whilst trying to configure it for `Rbbg` and the following worked for me `if(Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="") Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")`, check if it does for you

Comment: @Vivek I somehow solved the issue. I will delete this questions in a while if you dont mind. thanks

Comment: @Nick,if you could spare few minutes, could you post your own answer so that it helps others in the future, cheers

Answer (score 2):

So inside the R script i set a

`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre8')`

as shown above, pointing to my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Everything else is set as the Question shows.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: One note, this seems to only work with the JRE (Java Runtime Environment), you cannot use a JDK (Java Development Kit) install.

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting the comment on the original post, as the following specifically worked for me too:

> *"I had issues with rJava whilst trying to configure it for Rbbg and the following worked for me... check if it does for you –  Osssan May 2 '14 at 11:45"*

```java
if(Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="") Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="");
```